# Puppet : Did not receive certificate

Tags: ssl, puppet

I have a bare minimum, default puppet master/slave configuration on a newer version (6) of puppet which I'm attempting to initiate in virtualbox VMs for a prototype.  However, the agent doesnt seem to be able to properly connect to the master.

```
10.0.2.2 - - [14/Apr/2019:18:22:14 +0000] "GET /production/certificate/localhost? HTTP/1.1" 404 36 "-" "Ruby" 3
10.0.2.2 - - [14/Apr/2019:18:22:14 +0000] "GET /production/certificate/ca?fail_on_404=true HTTP/1.1" 200 1939 "-" "Ruby" 3
10.0.2.2 - - [14/Apr/2019:18:22:14 +0000] "GET /production/certificate/localhost? HTTP/1.1" 404 36 "-" "Ruby" 2
10.0.2.2 - - [14/Apr/2019:18:22:14 +0000] "GET /production/certificate/localhost? HTTP/1.1" 404 36 "-" "Ruby" 3
10.0.2.2 - - [14/Apr/2019:18:22:14 +0000] "GET /production/certificate/localhost? HTTP/1.1" 404 36 "-" "Ruby" 2
```

On my master, I only 2 certs, so clearly the request is getting through:

```
 "localhost" (SHA256) 1C:E7:D0:FF:35:A3:5B:CA:37:02:13:CC:75:20:B5:54:42:BA:AA:C9:61:9D:02:22:B3:28:E3:C3:4D:FE:5F:CC
  "slave1"    (SHA256) 35:A8:C5:E8:8A:1D:58:F6:DA:EC:8A:4D:9F:30:53:3E:F8:A1:01:27:F4:D7:62:5F:82:1C:E0:6B:37:82:A8:A2
```

My agent is able to connect just fine to the master, however, it seems to never get back a healthy cert:

```
Nothing to do
waiting to run puppet....
Info: Creating a new SSL key for localhost
Info: Caching certificate for ca
Info: csr_attributes file loading from /etc/puppet/csr_attributes.yaml
Info: Creating a new SSL certificate request for localhost
Info: Certificate Request fingerprint (SHA256): 1C:E7:D0:FF:35:A3:5B:CA:37:02:13:CC:75:20:B5:54:42:BA:AA:C9:61:9D:02:22:B3:28:E3:C3:4D:FE:5F:CC
Info: Caching certificate for ca

Notice: Did not receive certificate
Notice: Did not receive certificate
```

How can I determine why these 404 errors are occuring?

Comment: You have to sign the slave certificate on the puppet server so if you have puppet 6 then is 'puppetserver ca help' for more .. I am not yet using version 6.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you have to sign the certificate..
For Puppet Version 6 would be

```
puppetserver ca sign --certname slave1
```

For Puppet Version < 6

```
puppet cert sign slave1
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I hadn't signed my requests.

In order to do this, you simply use `puppet cert list` and then `puppet cert sign` to stand the outstanding request.  At that point, the server will be able to output a certificate, which the agent can then download and use locally.

Comment: Since it is a 'lab' setup, you could also turn on auto-signing